# Remove everything except letters from PHP string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

How can I remove everything from a string apart from letters? I have an input field for first names.

Comment: The tool for this is called regexp, which means regular expression. Yours basically accepts [a-zA-Z] and strips everything else. I however believe you are making a design mistake here. How about Marie-Madeleine and her friend N'gombe?

Comment: My name is Radosław - there are letters other than [a-zA-Z]. Also, if you want to restrict input for some reason, ask the user to fix it instead of grinding it yourself. I can be Radoslaw or Radek if your Americanocentric database is all out of 'ł's, but I won't like you if you make me a Radosaw.

Comment: As @rczajka points out, you'll have to be somewhat more flexible on the internets. Allowing just ASCII letters will fail many users. Rather use `preg_replace('/\PL/u', '', $str)` to filter non-letters.

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work? This is not a site for asking people to do your work for you; it's for getting help with things you're trying to do that isn't working. You have to at least put some effort into it yourself first.

Comment: Its time to accept an answer...

Answer (score 26):

In PHP, you can use (as suggested by @rczajka and @mario):

```
preg_replace('/\PL/u', '', $str)
```

Working Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/V78skl

You may want to checkout this [Tutorial for regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Your example link no longer works, but I've tested this and it works well with UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 14):

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i','',$old_string);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know. Why do we upvote unexplaned oneliners that don't even work?

Comment: @Martin I had a typo, writing 'Z' instead of 'z'.
But we all make typos, including you. (There is no '^' character in your regex in that codepad.)

Comment: This one is easier tp adjust for people without some special regex skills .. like me.

Answer (score -1):

```
$new_string = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "", $string );
```

Comment: Highly recommended you don't use this method: From PHP.net _This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged._ ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php)) Using it will throw an E_NOTICE error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize it had been deprecated. You can ignore this answer then.

Comment: DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0