# preg match everything except a letter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is there a shorthand for the opposite of this? `\p{L}`

I want to match everything except a letter.. `a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ ...`

You could of course do this `[^\p{L}]` but is there a shorter way of doing it?

Comment: Yes it is `\P{L}`

Comment: hehe.. of course.. :D create an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7264299/3832970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property `\P{L}` to may any unicode non-letter.

- `\P{L}` matches any characters that `\pL` does not

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6OO0H/1)